# Apple mach-o link error? Even though I imported frameworks

Tags: xcode

I'm getting a bunch of Apple Mach-O Linker errors because I'm missing some frameworks. However, when I checked the "Link binary with libraries" section of Build Phases and all the frameworks are already imported. So far I've tried removing all the frameworks and re-adding them as well as "Cleaning" (Product > clean) the app. Any ideas?

[image]

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Volumes/Install'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-FOS'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-FX'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-FYosemite/ROSHI_FINAL'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-Fcopy'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F5'
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork (3 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics (3 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/neilgandhi/Desktop/ROSHI_FINAL/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/neilgandhi/Desktop/ROSHI_FINAL/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation (3 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices (3 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore (3 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security (3 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox (3 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/StoreKit, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/StoreKit (3 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration (3 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation (3 slices)
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox', missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox (3 slices)
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMIDI.framework/CoreMIDI', missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMIDI.framework/CoreMIDI (3 slices)
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio', missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio (3 slices)
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation', missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation (3 slices)
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation', missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation (3 slices)
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia', missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia (3 slices)
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal', missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal (3 slices)
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo', missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo (3 slices)
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage', missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage (3 slices)
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES', missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES (3 slices)
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText', missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText (3 slices)
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit', missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit (3 slices)
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO', missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO (3 slices)
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit', missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit (3 slices)
```

Comment: Are you using any pods or other bundles which needs other frameworks?

Comment: Aside from Parse.com's framework, the only other library I'm using is SDWebImage

Comment: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage#add-linker-flag 
Add Linker Flag

Open the "Build Settings" tab, in the "Linking" section, locate the "Other Linker Flags" setting and add the "-ObjC" flag:

Comment: did u got the solution